# Insert request returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

so I have this function to insert data:

```html
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;


const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'self_learning',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432,
});

const createCategory = async (req, res) => {
   const {name,  parent} = req.body;

   pool.
    query('INSERT INTO categories ' +
            '(name, parent) ' +
            'VALUES ($1, $2)', [name, parent])
       .then(ponse => console.log(ponse.rows[0]))
       .catch(error => console.error(error.stack))
};
```

but the value in `then` statement returns as undefined, although the query is successfully executed.
I'm using the 'pg' library to connect to database

Comment: Did pool.query support promise or callback? means  pool.
    query(query, (err, result) => {})

Comment: `INSERT` doesn't return the inserted rows by default so I don't see anything weird... If you need to get values back, have you tried adding a `RETURNING` clause to the query?

Comment: @souravsatyam yes, this library does support promises

Comment: @AikaSat because I were checking this [https://blog.logrocket.com/setting-up-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-postgresql-d96d6fc892d8/] and didn't found promise support that is the reason I asked.

Comment: Then check ponse  object It may be ponse.data.rows[0]. May be.

Comment: @cogitoergosum could you please provide an example?

Comment: @AikaSat off the top of my head `INSERT .... VALUES($1,$2) RETURNING name, parent`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/dml-returning.html

Comment: @souravsatyam tried that too, still an empty array or just undefined , here's the official documentation to the library - https://node-postgres.com/features/queries

Comment: @AikaSat Then add RETURNING *   'INSERT INTO users(name, email) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING *' as the documentation says.